# Peewee - Using custom SQL as a subquery

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, peewee

I ran into a problem using Peewee with MySQL. Basically I want to filter the logs of my users and bin them into the last 8 weeks (say week 0 to week 7).
The result should look like:

```
{ 'userid': 1, 'week':1, 'bin': ?},
...
{ 'userid': 1, 'week':7, 'bin': ?},
{ 'userid': 2, 'week':0, 'bin': ?},
...
etc.
```

However, I want to ensure that even if the user has no entry in the log for a particular week, it still shows as 'bin': 0. I would use an OUTER JOIN, but I have no corresponding "week" table to OUTER JOIN with.
In SQL, I would do the following:

```
WITH  weeks (week) AS (
VALUES ROW(0),ROW(1),ROW(2),ROW(3),ROW(4),ROW(5),ROW(6),ROW(7)
)'
```

and then use "weeks" in the join. However I can't figure out how to do this in peewee. If I create a "RawQuery" I cannot use it for joining as I would do with a regular query (it has no .c to access the fields or .select()).

I ended up using a dirty fix like this, on a table that has not too many records:

```py
max_weeks = 8
weeks = (
    MyTable.select(
        (fn.MOD(MyTable.id,max_weeks)).alias("week")
    ).distinct()
)
```

but I would prefer to do it the right way.

I must specify here that my requirement is that I make only **one** query (composed of multiple subqueries) to the database, and that the number of weeks (8 in this case) is variable. Also, I have **read-only** permission on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MySQL handy as I use MariaDB which uses slightly different syntax, but hopefully something like this should work:

```
from peewee import *
from peewee import NodeList, CommaNodeList, CTE

db = MySQLDatabase('peewee_test')

class Reg(db.Model):
    value = IntegerField()

db.create_tables([Reg])
Reg.create(value=1)

weeks = CommaNodeList([fn.ROW(i) for i in range(8)])

cte = CTE('weeks', NodeList([SQL('VALUES'), weeks]), columns=['week'])

# Just a simple cartesian product of Reg x Weeks - in your example
# you would be performing a join instead.
query = Reg.select(Reg.value, cte.c.week).from_(Reg, cte).with_cte(cte)
print(query.sql())
for row in query:
    print(row.value, row.week)
```

The SQL generated:

```
WITH `weeks` (`week`) AS (
    VALUES ROW(0), ROW(1), ROW(2), ROW(3),
           ROW(4), ROW(5), ROW(6), ROW(7)) 
SELECT `t1`.`value`, `weeks`.`week` 
FROM `reg` AS `t1`, `weeks`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for !

I would only mention that the two first lines of your imports are redundant.